# In Fast and Slow Pointer problems, why check for fast.next and why are we not checking fast.next.next

Tags: pointers, linked-list

I'm looking at LeetCode problem [141. Linked List Cycle](https://leetcode.com/problems/linked-list-cycle/):

> Given `head`, the head of a linked list, determine if the linked list has a cycle in it.
>
> There is a cycle in a linked list if there is some node in the list that can be reached again by continuously following the `next` pointer. Internally, `pos` is used to denote the index of the node that tail's `next` pointer is connected to. **Note that `pos` is not passed as a parameter.**
>
> Return `true` *if there is a cycle in the linked list*. Otherwise, return `false`.

I saw this solution:

```
function hasCycle(head) {
    let fast = head
    let slow = head
    while (fast && fast.next) {
        fast = fast.next.next
        slow = slow.next
        if (fast == slow) return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Why does it check for `fast.next` and why are we not checking `fast.next.next`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checks that need to be done are there to avoid doing something that will evaluate to `(null).next`, which would raise an error.

If you then look at the body of the loop, you see we do `fast = fast.next.next`, so there are two accesses to `next`. We need to ensure those accesses are not made on a `null` value. Hence, we should check:

- that in `fast.next` we don't have `fast` equal to `null`
- that when the previous check is ok, that in `fast.next.next` we don't have `fast.next` equal to `null`

That should explain why the `while` condition is like it is.

There is no need to check that `fast.next.next` is not `null`, as a `null` at that level will not trigger an error. It would just mean that in the iteration of the loop, `fast` will be set to `null`, but that is a valid operation.